# Why neo4j is memory demanding as a database

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j recently. My data size is only moderate: a little less than 5 million nodes, around 24 million edges and 30 million properties. This data size is not huge according to traditional relational database such as MySQL or Oracle. But when I run neo4j, it seems quite memory demanding. To me, a database should not be memory demanding: if you have sufficient memory and allow to use as much, it will perform faster. But if you don't have much memory, it should still work. But for neo4j, it is interrupted (due to low memory) sometimes (not consistently but is annoying enough as I expect a database to be much more reliable).

To be more specific, I have a Linux machine that has 8G memory. I only allow an initial and max heap size of 2G to run the graph data.

Anyone experiencing something similar? Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have a lot of big transactions open on it at once? Any open transactions are stored in heap until they commit, so if you are sending multiple statements to the same transaction, you'll run into heap problems. Those parameters are very much the low end for neo4j, but I've got servers with the same limits and expectations without memory problems, so it may be a usage issue. What activity is triggering the OOM errors?

Comment: Hmm, I got the logs:
The response of the WebApplicationException cannot be utilized as the response is already comm$
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException

Comment: If it is a problem with heap memory, you should see something in `$NEO_HOME/logs/debug.log`. UPDATE: I can't help any further with that error, unfortunately, it is well over my head. I don't think it's a heap problem, though.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and is off-topic for StackOverflow. Might be a good question for Neo Technology specifically, perhaps on a support forum, twitter, github issue, etc. But not here.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j uses off-heap RAM to cache the graph to speed up reading nodes, relationships and properties.

You can tweak the amount of memory being used for caching by setting `dbms.memory.pagecache.size`.